# what does the paint method? how does it work?

Tags: java, oop, applet, awt, paint

what does the paint method do after receiving the object created from the Graphics class as a parameter?

as for example in this code:

```
public class unaClase extends Applet{
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200);
    }
}
```

try to trace the source to see its code and thus be able to understand what it does, but it does not show me anything

[image]

***What I want is to know what makes paint with the parameter it receives?***

PD: I know that apple is dead, I just want to understand well what is happening, what it does

Comment: Applet is not "outdated"; applets are completely **dead**.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your asking?  How to paint using a graphic context can be a very lengthy discussion.

Comment: @WJS when I use the **paint** _method_ (as in the example code), I'm technically **overwriting** it (unless I had used _super.paint ..._), and then its code would be the one I just defined; so my question is, how does **paint** know what to do with the parameter (**Graphics**) that I'm going through?

Comment: You're *overriding* it, not *overwriting* it. paint() knows what to do because you told it what to do by adding instructions in the method implementation: `g.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200);`. So that's what it does.

Comment: @JBNizet So it paint would become a code capsule so that the g (of Graphics) object can be executed along with its methods?

Comment: I have no idea of what a code capsule is. Here's how I would explain the paint method. Imagine your job is to display ads for customers on a billboard, and to redisplay it again when the ad is damaged. That's basically what an applet is. Now imagine I'm your customer. In order for me to display whatever I want on the billboard, you give me a big piece of paper along with some painting and drawing tools (that's the Graphics object). I do whatever I want with them (like drawing a rectangle), and then you display what I painted on the paper (the rectangle) on the billboard.

Comment: If the drawing is damaged, you give me another piece of paper (i.e. you call paint again with a Graphics), and I paint my rectangle again (or whatever I want to paint if I decide to paint something else), then you display my new drawing on the billboard.

Comment: @JBNizet I was somewhat confused, but I already understood, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> when I use the paint method (as in the example code), I'm technically overwriting it (unless I had used super.paint ...), and then its code would be the one I just defined; so my question is, how does paint know what to do with the parameter (Graphics) that I'm going through?

The actual term is `overriding`.  And the first thing you would normally do is call `super.paint()` to the parent version.  `Graphics` (or `Graphics2D` which has additional methods but needs to be cast) allows one to use those methods to draw, rotate, and in general manipulate pixels.  It is handled internally using native method calls that are supported by the OS.

If you are going to paint you should do it in a `JPanel` and override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`.  Check out the tutorials on painting at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html